# Links working in Firefox, not Chrome

Tags: css, hyperlink, cross-browser, flip

I've been working on creating a CSS "flip" container that has links on the back side...

However, anytime I put in a link code on the reverse side, the links do not work in Chrome, but they work in FireFox.

Here is the page:

http://beta2.thrivemusic.com/artists/

If you hover over "Steve Aoki", the image flips and reveals 3 social icons.  The social icons are supposed to be linked to another page, but these links do not work in Chrome, only firefox...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please put sample code on a site like http://jsfiddle.net, as the link to your final site will be worthless to posterity once you've fixed the problem.

Comment: Also it'd be helpful if you'd describe what "do not work" means: what do you expect to happen, and what actually happens instead.

Comment: (First Question Review), can you reduce it to a minimum sample code yo u can include in the question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/samkimdesign/A7MZ3/

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `backface-visibility` on `#f1_card` or set it to `inherit`.

```
#f1_card {
      backface-visibility: inherit;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Also, change those IDs to classes if they're going to be repeated.

Comment: Thank you, that solved some of the issues I'm trying to resolve!